# Easiest/best back end layer to tie MS SQL database and ExtJS front end

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis, extjs, ria

We currently have a big project that consists of the following layers:

- MS SQL Server database
- Microsoft RIA WCF Service layer
- IIS and
- ExtJS web application

Everything works more or less. The only my concern is I think second layer is a bit over kill and over complicated for what we have on the front end - the whole task for it is to generate JSON messages with the data from the database. This structure was chosen because originally we were planning to use Silverlight as a front end (thank God! we decide to drop it in the favor of ExtJs btw).

Now I have couple other web projects on the horizon and I'm wondering if dropping this second layer (RIA WCF) is the right choice. What are my other options if I decide to stick with MSSQL/IIS/ExtJs? If somebody had experience with something else I would appreciate any feedback. Any links would be very helpful too.

Comment: You cannot simply "drop it" as a web page cannot connect directly to SQL server.  You need something that bridges the HTTP protocol, which the webpage can send, with the T-SQL protocol, which SQL server can receive.  That something is currently a WCF layer. If you want to drop WCF you need to consider other alternatives, and to do that you need to get clear about *why* you're considering droppoing WCF, and what advantages might be available in other frameworks.  I will make one suggestion: ASPNET MVC.  Very simple and easy to use, works with IIS and SQL, speaks JSON fluently.

Comment: You're correct. I would need something else. That's the question basically. So what are or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) and [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). Entity Framework is useful for mapping your SQL Database into business objects that can be handled via MVC and displayed using ExtJs and the [Razor view engine](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-3/mvc-3-razor-view-engine).